# Split string on words that start with colon

Tags: ruby, string, split

I'm trying to make a method that takes a part of a key in a hash and compares that to a value in input. The key looks likes this:

```
policy :allow ,:denied ,:closed
```

I'm trying to split this key to get only `allow`, `denied`, `closed` so that I can compare those to the values I'm getting input.

I have this right now:

```
key.split(/: */)
```

This gives me:

```
policy closed, allow, denied
```

How do I get rid of the first word `policy` and the `,`?

Comment: Your question concerns string manipulation. The fact that the string is a key in a hash is irrelevant. Mentioning that only muddies the water. You need to enclose your string in single or double quotes to make it a valid Ruby object, both to clarify what it is and to facilitate cutting and pasting (and avoid downvotes). When you give an example always show your desired output (as a valid Ruby object) and assign a variable to each input object (`str = "policy :allow ,:denied ,:closed"`) so  readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like to use Regex, it can be intimidating.
So I always try to look for an alternative.

This is my version (a simple regex-pattern):

```
str = 'policy :allow, :denied, :closed'

policies1 = str.scan /(?<=:)\w+/
policies2 = str.split(/, :|:/)[1..-1]

#=> ["allow", "denied", "closed"]

require 'benchmark'


n = 5000000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("scan")   { for i in 1..n;  policies = str.scan /(?<=:)\w+/ ; end }
  x.report("split")  { for i in 1..n;  policies = str.split(/, :|:/)[1..-1] ; end }
end
```

With this result

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------
scan   15.670000   0.050000  15.720000 ( 15.725932)
split  13.050000   0.110000  13.160000 ( 13.160543)
------------------------------- total: 28.880000sec

            user     system      total        real
scan   16.130000   0.080000  16.210000 ( 16.217341)
split  12.980000   0.100000  13.080000 ( 13.095190)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need for a regular expression:

```
str = 'policy :allow ,:denied ,:closed'
str.tr(':,', '').split[1..-1] # => ["allow", "denied", "closed"]
```

This is really a problem of removing garbage then splitting on whitespace and grabbing certain fields.

Here's what's happening:

```
str.tr(':,', '') # => "policy allow denied closed"
str.tr(':,', '').split # => ["policy", "allow", "denied", "closed"]
str.tr(':,', '').split[1..-1] # => ["allow", "denied", "closed"]
```

It's really important to remember to start as simple as possible to accomplish a task, then get more complicated if a problem arises. Maintainability is the #1 concern and regex used frivolously can be a pain. Used correctly it's amazingly powerful, but it's not a universal panacea and not everything is a nail needing to be hit by the regex hammer.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's `Regexp` supports **lookahead** and **lookbehind**. In your case, you can use **positive lookbehind**.

```
str = 'policy :allow, :denied, :closed'
policies = str.scan /(?<=:)\w+/
#=> ["allow", "denied", "closed"]
```

The regular expression above looks for **words** `\w+` which are **prefixed with a colon** `(?<=:)`. Note that the `(?<=)` is so called **positive lookbehind**, which is a zero-length match.

Comment: Hey could you explain the regex you used ? :)

Comment: Perfectly valid ruby code: `policy :✓, :✗` will hardly pass this regexp, though OP did not mention the _real intent_.

Comment: @mudasobwa: oh come on :) This is a reasonable assumption, I'd say.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not at all. Guess how `params[:utf8]` looks in Rails since the Stone Age? :)

Comment: This is the best [IMHO] tutorial on the subject: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @mudasobwa: but it's not a method name! Besides, does anyone actually use it? :)

Comment: thnx alot guys! :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If “anyone” means “mudasobwa included,” than yes, method names like `✍` for `debug` and `⚑` for `airbrake` are hardly used nowadays. Give it a try and you’ll love this approach, it saves keypresses and brings aesthetics!

Comment: @NielDejonghe please mark the answer as correct if it was helpful. “thnx a lot guys!” is good for a foam party, not for this site.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev bah :) but then perfect greppability. Another cool tweak is making methods “private by contract” by using Cyrillic in method names.

Comment: Two alternatives: `str.scan /:\K\w+/` and `str.scan(/:(\w+)/).flatten`. `\K` means, roughly, "forget everything matched so far".

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be:

```
str = 'policy :allow, :denied, :closed'  # "policy :allow, :denied, :closed"
arr = str.split(":")  # ["policy ", "allow, ", "denied, ", "closed"]
arr = arr.pop(arr.length - 1)  # ["allow, ", "denied, ", "closed"]
arr.map{|text| text.gsub(", ", "")} # ["allow", "denied", "closed"]
```

Comment: Instead of `arr = arr.pop(arr.length - 1)` a simple `arr.shift` would suffice.